# Kubernetes (Minikube) volume is mounted (from Airflow Helm values) but remains empty

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, minikube, docker-volume

I would  like to deploy Airflow locally on Minikube and have a local folder mounted for DAGs handling.

Airflow is deployed like this:

```
helm install $AIRFLOW_NAME apache-airflow/airflow \
    --values values.yml \
    --set logs.persistence.enabled=true \
    --namespace $AIRFLOW_NAMESPACE \
    --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config
```

The `values.yml` looks like this:

```
executor: KubernetesExecutor
config:
  core:
    dags_folder: /dags
webserver:
  extraVolumes:
    - name: dags
      hostPath:
        path: /path/dags
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: dags
      mountPath: /dags
```

`kubectl describe pods airflow-webserver --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config  --namespace airflow`:

```
Volumes:
  config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      airflow-airflow-config
    Optional:  false
  logs:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  airflow-logs
    ReadOnly:   false
  dags:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /path/dags/
    HostPathType:  
  airflow-webserver-token-xtq9h:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  airflow-webserver-*
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
```

The volume dags appears to be correctly mounted but remains empty.
What could cause this behaviour ?

Edit:
`kubectl describe pods airflow-scheduler-0 --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config --namespace airflow`

```
    Mounts:
      /opt/airflow/airflow.cfg from config (ro,path="airflow.cfg")
      /opt/airflow/dags from dags (rw)
      /opt/airflow/logs from logs (rw)
      /opt/airflow/pod_templates/pod_template_file.yaml from config (ro,path="pod_template_file.yaml")
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from airflow-scheduler-token-9zfpv (ro)
```

```
Volumes:
  config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      airflow-airflow-config
    Optional:  false
  dags:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /path/dags
    HostPathType:  
  logs:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  airflow-logs
    ReadOnly:   false
  airflow-scheduler-token-9zfpv:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  airflow-scheduler-token-9zfpv
    Optional:    false
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have some dags in /path/dags already, you should mount your dags folder to scheduler not to webserver (if you are using Airflow 2). Scheduler is the one to parse dags, webserver only displays them based on information stored in the DB so it does not actually need DAGs (it used to need it Airflow 1.10 without serialization)

Also I guess you should use LocalExecutor not KubernetesExecutor if you want to execute dags from local folder - then the `dags` mounted to scheduler will be available to the processes which are spawned from scheduler in the same container.

If you want to run Kubernetes Executor and want to mount host folder, I believe you will need to add it as a mount to pod template file of yours (you can generate such pod template file using airflow CLI

See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/kubernetes.html#pod-template-file

Comment: I added the same extraVolumes / extraVolumeMounts to the scheduler and tried with both LocalExecutor and KubernetesExecutor but couldn't get to see my DAG on the webserver UI. The mounted DAG folder on the scheduler is empty aswell. The problem seems related to the mount that doesn't append my local DAG files isn't it ?

I will try with the pod_template_file aswell, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I was completely mistaking the `hostPath` parameter for my local machine.
`hostPath` refers to the Minikube node running the pod.

```
  extraVolumes:
    - name: dags
      hostPath:
        path: /mnt/airflow/dags
        type: Directory
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: dags
      mountPath: /opt/airflow/dags
```

This will mount a volume between the Minikube host node and the port.
The path `/mnt/airflow/dags` **must not be present on the local machine**.

The local DAGs folder can then be mounted into the Minikube node:

`minikube mount ./dags/:/mnt/airflow/dags`

See: https://medium.com/@ipeluffo/running-apache-airflow-locally-on-kubernetes-minikube-31f308e3247a

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your mount folder is empty is because I guess you are using Docker Desktop on MaCOS (that's my wild guess)

Your dags have to be present in the /path/dags folder on the host however in case of Docker Desktop on MacOS (similarly on Windows) your host is a virtual machine not the MacOS/Windows.

In this case you need to make sure that /path/dags from your host is also mapped to the virtual machine (by default only those folders are mapped:

Via: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/

> By default the /Users, /Volume, /private, /tmp and /var/folders directory are shared

You can add new folders from your host to be shared as well (See "File sharing" chapter in the document above)

Comment: Hi Jarek, I use Ubuntu 20.04.2 and Docker 20.10.7. I don't see any reason why my local files don't appear on my mounted folder

Comment: Yeah  - that's strange. Are you sure you are using local docker engine ? Maybe there is some kind of isolation there. I wonder if you run `docker run -it -v /path/dags:/paths/dags bash` would you see your dags there?

Comment: I do see my dags there by typing this command ! I tried running `minikube start --driver=docker` and it shows `Preparing Kubernetes v1.20.7 on Docker 20.10.7` which refers my local docker version